# How can I implement the merge and score functionality of 2048?

Tags: javascript, arrays, 2048

Here's the problem, simplified to the problem that I'm facing.

I have an object, consisting of a score counter and an arbitrary 1D array of elements, filled with numbers:

```
{ score: 0, board: [4, 2, 2] }
```

I am looking for a function, that will do a 2048-ish move left (as if these numbers are tiles are on one row of a 2048 game board), and will also add score to the counter (merging into an 8 adds 8 to the score).

I have searched, and found functions, that do this, but i found none that also counted score. how can I accomplish this?

Here are some test cases:

```js
{ score: 0, board: []          } => { score: 0,    board: []     }
{ score: 0, board: [2,2]       } => { score: 4,    board: [4]    }
{ score: 4, board: [2,2,2]     } => { score: 8,    board: [4,2]  }
{ score: 6, board: [4,2,2]     } => { score: 10,   board: [4,4]  }
{ score: 0, board: [2,2,2,2]   } => { score: 8,    board: [4,4]  }
{ score: 8, board: [4,4]       } => { score: 16,   board: [8]    }
{ score: 2, board: [8,8]       } => { score: 18,   board: [16]   }
{ score: 0, board: [16,16]     } => { score: 32,   board: [32]   }
{ score: 0, board: [1024,1024] } => { score: 2048, board: [2048] }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I would suggest to break down the task and solve the smaller parts first, then put them together. You have to find repeating numbers in an array. You have to add them together. You have to modify the array. You have to increase the score. You have to repeat this until there are no more repeating numbers in the array. Which part causes you trouble?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0mzbt8jg/1/ here's a test space for the function

Comment: @juzraai all of those tasks, i don't know where to start and can't find anything online, at all. also, it shouldn't repeat until there aren't any duplicate numbers left - [2,2,2,2] should result in [4,4].

Comment: In that example, should the `[4,4]` not then continue to reduce to `[8]`? Also, you have a type in your testing, it should say `x.expected` but says `x.ecpected`

Comment: @juzraai thanks, your comment actually gave me an idea on how to do this, and my function is working and has passed all tests. do i post it as a self-answer?

Comment: @Stitt oh yeah, i see, however, i can't edit the fiddle as i posted it anonymously. and no, in a game of 2048, merging a row of four 2s doesn't result in an 8.

Comment: In 2048 you can merge two 4s to create an 8 though, correct?

Comment: @Stitt yes, but that happens on the next move. [2,2,2,2] => [8] isn't the functionality that i am looking for.

Comment: If there was a close reason for this question, it'd be "not enough clarity"... but not "not focused". I kind of don't get it, could someone explain?

Comment: See the [close reasons guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417476/question-close-reasons-definitions-and-guidance). "Needs details and clarity" and "Needs more focus" often overlap. Some people consider the question "too broad" when it only asks "how to do xxx" without further details. Anyway, always better to write a clear question from the beginning, because reopening takes usually much more time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A comment under my post gave me an idea on how to approach this, and I wrote a function, that has passed all of my tests:

```js
const mergeFunc = ({score, board}) => {
  let returnObject = {
    score: score,
    board: [...board] // just in case
  };
  for(let i=0; i<returnObject.board.length-1; i++)
  // parsing through the array left to right,
    if(returnObject.board[i] === returnObject.board[i+1]){
    // if an element is the same as the element to it's right,
      returnObject.score += returnObject.board[i]*2;
      // add the value of the new tile to the score,
      returnObject.board.splice(i,2,returnObject.board[i]*2)
      // and merge the two tiles.
    }
  return returnObject;
}

console.log(mergeFunc({score:0,board:[2,2,2,2]}))
```

The function iterates over the array left to right, merging any two identical neighbouring numbers that it finds using `.splice()`, and adds the value of the new cell to the score.

Here's the function, edited to work for 2D arrays (though, it still only merges left):

```js
const mergeFunc2D = ({score, board}) => {
  let returnObject = {
    score: score || 0,
    board: board.map(x=>x.filter(y=>y!==undefined))
  };
  for(let j=0; j<returnObject.board.length; j++) { // for each array:
    for(let i=0; i<returnObject.board[j].length-1; i++) // parsing through the array left to right,
      if(returnObject.board[j][i] === returnObject.board[j][i+1]){ // if an element is the same as the element to it's right,
        returnObject.score += returnObject.board[j][i]*2; // add the value of the new tile to the score,
        returnObject.board[j].splice(i,2,returnObject.board[j][i]*2) // and merge the two tiles.
      }
      // optionally, cut to specific width and pad with undefs
      returnObject.board[j] = returnObject.board[j].concat([undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined]).splice(0,4);
  }
  return returnObject;
}
console.log(mergeFunc2D({
  board:[
    [2,2,undefined,undefined],
    [2,undefined,2,2],
    [2,2,2,2],
    [2,2,4,4],
  ]
}))
```